# Get the value of a parameter in resolve of ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

I will use `window.open` to open a url like `https://localhost:3000/new?HostId=8Ocs_Onuv1wowozxAAAS&_host_Info=excel%7Cweb%7C16.00%7Cen-us%7Cc8b501ce-c51d-b862-701e-5c623e1a70e0%7CisDialog`.

`https://localhost:3000` hosts a mean-stack site. I want to get the value of `HostId` (eg, `8Ocs_Onuv1wowozxAAAS`) in the resolve of ui-router. I have tried the follows, but it did not work:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('new',
            url: '/new/:HostId',
            templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
            controller: 'EditorCtrl',
            resolve: {
                host: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify($stateParams))
                }]
            }
        });
}]);
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Your states URL should probably be `url: '/new?HostId',`

Comment: Remove JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing HostId in your code . Change your code to

```
 resolve: {
        host: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
            alert($stateParams.HostId)
        }]
```

And type of $stateParams is string you dont need stringify it

Comment: Additionally, as @Chris mentioned, URL should be `url: '/new?HostId'`...